# Angular 2 PUT request not working with spring rest controller

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, angular

I'm trying to update an object's attribute by passing it's id on a PUT request in angular 2 like this:

```
accept(id : string){
    return this.http.put('/myurl/accept/' +id).map(res => res.json());      
}
```

And my rest controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "accept/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.OK )
public void accept(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    System.out.println("It works");
    service.accept(id);     
}
```

But the controller method is never called ( I never see the 'It works' msg ), doesn't my put request match the pattern I'm declaring at the controller or is it something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you ever subscribe() to the observable returned by accept()? If you don't, then the request is never sent. Also check the network tab of the dev tools in your browser.

Comment: I was not subcribing i totally forgot about it because i was receiving the id in accept() properly, now it works, thanks for your time.